# JQuery Animation not working as expected

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm working with a simple animation instruction:

```
$('.slide').stop().animate({ queue: true, marginTop: total + 'px' }, (2000 * 2 * times), function () {
        alert('in');
    });
```

Where the marginTop of a `<div class="slide"></div>` is being manipulated.

Now, the issue comes here:

As you can see, the app should only show ONE alert saying "IN", because the alert
is performed in the animation-end function. However, the alert is being shown more than
once...

why?

p.s: I don't have loops or so in my code...

Thx

Comment: Why do you have `queue: true` among your list of style properties? That is meant to be part of the *options* argument that you can optionally pass as the second argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason for this is that you have more than one element in your markup which owns a classname of `slide`.  jQuery will apply that animation to each element which was queried by your selector.

Unless you don't possibly call that code multiple times of course.